# Total Novice problem with loading and playing a video file

Tags: html, video

Trying to build a webpage that will allow a visitor to upload and play a video from their hard-drive (a-la YouTube).

The file seems to load but it won't play. Using Dreamweaver. Outputting to chrome. Thanks!

```
<video autoplay id="video" controls>
  <source id="source" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
<br /><br />
<input type="file" name="file" onchange="SelectedVideo(this);" />
<script>
  function selectedVideo(self) {
    var file = self.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function (e) {
      var src = e.target.result;
      var video = document.getElementById("video");
      var source = document.getElementById("source");

      source.setAttribute("src", src);
      video.load();
      video.play();
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `SelectedVideo` but your function is defined as `selectedVideo`

Just change that and it should work.

```
<video autoplay id="video" controls>
  <source id="source" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
<br /><br />
<input type="file" name="file" onchange="selectedVideo(this);" /> 
                                         ^^^^ here is the problem
<script>
  function selectedVideo(self) {
    var file = self.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function (e) {
      var src = e.target.result;
      var video = document.getElementById("video");
      var source = document.getElementById("source");

      source.setAttribute("src", src);
      video.load();
      video.play();
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works now. Have to be more careful with my cases in the future.